# Task in metro style application

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I have a question regarding Task in metro style applications (winrt).

Thread's are not available (at least since windows 8.1/windows phone 8.1), so to perform asynchronous operations we have to use Task now.

- When I create Task and call Run doest it create new Thread? If so is there a way to kill/stop that Thread?
- All Tasks are part of application procces - so when I call Application.Current.Exit() does it stops all Tasks (In case I have not properly stopped/closed/ended them ?) If not Is it possuble? In Thread you could set IsBackground property to force to close them whem application was closed.
- What happens to Tasks when the application is suspended? And what are guidelines ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I create Task and call Run does it create new Thread? If so is there a way to kill/stop that Thread?

It doesn't create a new thread, it will use a thread from the thread pool. This is assuming you haven't passed any other `TaskScheduler`.

> If so is there a way to kill/stop that Thread?

There is a way to do cooperative cancellation via the `CancellationToken` and `CancellationTokenSource` structures. There is no way to abort a `Task` such as with `Thread.Abort`. `Task != Thread`.

> so when I call Application.Current.Exit() does it stops all Tasks

Threadpool threads are background by default, they won't prolong the life of your application like a foreground thread. You're safe to assume once the application has closed, all threads are terminated.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation! That's exacly what I was looking for :)